# How to change screen color according to listView item

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

I want to make a horizontal listview and the background color change when the new item appears on the screen 
Like [this](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/300593/screenshots/10813423/media/77e898866416e030076a376649e470b7.mp4)
I could not do it with listview because I couldn't change the container color according to the current item index 
Any ideas about how to do this?

P S. I made an animation container and its child is a page view but what I want is a list view not a page view

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _index = 0;
  List<Color> colors = [
  Colors.yallow,
  Colors.blue
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final restData = Provider.of<ResturantsProvider>(context);
    final rest = restData.rest;

    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.linear,
        color: colors[_index],
        child: PageView.builder(
          onPageChanged: (i) {
            setState(() {
              _index = i;
            });
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: rest.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                LogoHomePage(
                  logoImg: rest[index].logoImg,
                ),
                ResturantListView(
                  restImg: rest[index].restImg,
                  restName: rest[index].restName,
                  restRate: rest[index].restRate,
                  restType: rest[index].restType,
                  time: rest[index].time,
                  color: rest[index].color,
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code, what you've tried so far and where you're struggling?

Comment: so to be clear, if the colors are known it's easy but are you talking about automatic detection where color is dynamic and unpredictable which requires automatic detection?

Comment: @Manuel  I added my code

Comment: @Henok yes, the colors are known as a list what I mean is how to set my variable to match the listview index so I can add my known color to be full the screen.

Comment: so here the real question is how to track the index of the visible item inside listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [inview_notifier_list](https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list) with listview in a container, set isInViewPortCondition as your requirement and then change container color

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your listview children (each) with VisibilityDetector,

```
VisibilityDetector(
   key: Key("yourKey"),
   onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
       //get visibilityInfo here
       //pass the index of child to parent here based on that parent changes color
   },
   child: YourListItemChild();
)
```